# Calling constructor for Unity injected class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have this as my MS Unity code, with two implementations of the IDatabase interface registered. EmpCatalogue's constructor implements one of these databases and is created with the Unity resolve method.

```
IUnityContainer objContainer = new UnityContainer();

objContainer.RegisterType<EmpCatalogue>();
objContainer.RegisterType<IDatabase, Database>();
objContainer.RegisterType<IDatabase, XmlDatabase>();

EmpCatalogue emp = objContainer.Resolve<EmpCatalogue>();
```

In my program there is another class that creates an instance of `EmpCatalogue`, but the constructor has no parameters.

```
public class UI_Controller
{
    public EmpCatalogue empcat = new EmpCatalogue();
}
```

The constructor for the `EmpCatalogue` looks like this.

```
public EmpCatalogue(IDatabase idb)
{
    this.idb = idb;
}
```

I am unsure how to instantiate a class that is registered in the Unity Container in another class. Should i refactor my code so as to avoid this, or is there a way to get the reference for the `EmpCatalogue` to use in the `UI_Controller` class?

Comment: Which `IDatabase` implementation does `EmpCatalogue` require? `Database` or `XmlDatabase`? And what happens when `EmpCatalogue` gets the other implementation? Will it keep working or will it break?